# RecyclerView Adapter cannot update view immediately when adding new item by clicking the button

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have one Activity which contains viewpager inside and each viewpager tab contains one fragment . only one of these fragment has one recyclerview (which has inside cardView)and of course one adapter for the recyclerview . by clicking on floating action button which is in Main Activtiy layout another Activity open that contains two edit texts one for device id and one for device name and one button called Add .by clicking the add button it should add the device to the database and update adapter using notifyItemInserted(position) .... the problem here it add the device to the database immediately but the adapter not update the view immediately . it update after i scroll through the app using viewpager tabs or when i start the main activity from the beginning .... there is no error in the code and i have search for answer but i couldn't find anything to solve this issue ..

anyone face like this problem please advice
thanks

Comment: Please provide some code you've already written.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Code and logcat, please!

Answer (score 1):

Try swapadapter() method for the same.

```
 void swapAdapter (Adapter adapter, 
            boolean removeAndRecycleExistingViews)
```

Swaps the current adapter with the provided one. It is similar to setAdapter(Adapter) but assumes existing adapter and the new adapter uses the same RecyclerView.ViewHolder and does not clear the RecycledViewPool.

Comment: when i use this method i got this

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter, boolean)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call your SetUpRecyclerView in onActivityResult() which I asume your are using. That is what I use when adding elements to My RecyclerViews.
When using FragmentPagerAdapter, Your pager keeps two tabs in memory, that's why you have to scroll for the changes to take effect. But for me calling my SetupRecyclerView works just fine.

Comment: you cannot careate  onActivityResult()  method inside recyclerview adapter

Comment: @Laity Rawi, dude I think that you need to add your code or relevant of it to your original post. Although I understand your question with no code, no idea what you might be doing.